# Handle ClickEvent by PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown in Behavior<FrameworkElement>

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouseevent, behavior

I have a `Behavior<FrameworkElement>` where I register `PreviewKeyDown` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`. I have attached this `Behavior` on a `MenuItem`. Now when I click on the `MenuItem`, sometimes the `ClickEvent` is still invoked and sometimes not. It is like a timing problem. Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem and stop invoke the `event`?

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    base.OnAttached();
    AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += _OnPreviewKeyDown;
    AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += _OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
}

private void _OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
{
    if (!_HasAccess())
        mouseButtonEventArgs.Handled = true;
}

private void _OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
{
    if (!_HasAccess())
        keyEventArgs.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: `FrameworkElement` has no `ClickEvent`. I want to attach this `Behavior` to any `Control` I want to and 'control' the click event.

Comment: This will be a kind of "SecurityBehavior". If the User has not the permission for a control (`Button`, `MenuItem`..), the `Click` should be handled/blocked and a kind of "LoginPopup" is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had to subscribe to `AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` and set `handled = true`. Now I got the desired behavior!